# WD Elements portable has only /dev/sg entry but no /dev/sd on linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I am troubleshooting a [WDBU6Y0020BBK-0B](https://www.westerndigital.com/en-us/products/portable-drives/wd-elements-portable-usb-3-0-hdd) external hard drive of a colleague on Ubuntu Linux. It shows up as /dev/sg3, but has no /dev/sdx entry. My problem is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/225314/cant-mount-linux-usb-disk-it-just-create-dev-sg-device-but-no-dev-sd), but the output of `lsscsi -l` is different. In particular I see `device_blocked=1`. Because of this and because there was no feedback on whether it worked, I am hesitant to try overwriting the MBR as suggested in [this reply](https://superuser.com/a/645341). What would happen to the data on the drive in this case?

Now in more detail:

The only new device in `ls /dev/` after plugging in the drive is: `sg3`.

The output of `sudo fdisk -l` remains unchanged.

`sudo mount /dev/sg3 /mnt` gives me:

```
mount: /mnt: /dev/sg3 ist kein blockorientiertes Gerät.
```

(translating to: is not a block device)

`sudo sg_map` gives me:

```
/dev/sg0  /dev/sda
/dev/sg1  /dev/sdb
/dev/sg2  /dev/sr0
/dev/sg3
```

`lsscsi -l` gives me:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST500LM021-1KJ15 LIM1  /dev/sda 
  state=running queue_depth=32 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      TS256GMTS430S    T2DA  /dev/sdb 
  state=running queue_depth=32 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8E2    1.00  /dev/sr0 
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=5 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[6:0:0:0]    disk    WD       Elements 25A2    1021  -        
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=7 type=0 device_blocked=1 timeout=30
```

Here we see compared to [the other question](https://superuser.com/questions/225314/cant-mount-linux-usb-disk-it-just-create-dev-sg-device-but-no-dev-sd), that we have an actual value (`1021`) in the fifth column and we see `device_blocked=1`. The only result on Google for "lsscsi "device_blocked=1"" is [this](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/115507-troubleshooting-parity-sync-errors/), which describes a very different problem and remains inconclusive.

Relevant part of `sudo lsusb -v`:

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1058 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
  idProduct          0x25a2 Elements 25A2
  bcdDevice           10.21
  iManufacturer           1 Western Digital
  iProduct                2 Elements 25A2
  iSerial                 3 575842314143373841414146
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x002c
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              896mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000f0e
      BESL Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
    BESL value     3840 us 
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat          32 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x000c
  (Bus Powered)
  U1 Enabled
  U2 Enabled
```

`dmesg` after attaching the drive gives me:

```
[180282.463438] usb 4-5: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[180282.484494] usb 4-5: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25a2, bcdDevice=10.21
[180282.484510] usb 4-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[180282.484517] usb 4-5: Product: Elements 25A2
[180282.484522] usb 4-5: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[180282.484526] usb 4-5: SerialNumber: 575842314143373841414146
[180282.486273] usb-storage 4-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[180282.486630] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-5:1.0
[180283.515654] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 25A2    1021 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[180283.516233] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[180283.517152] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[180284.539232] ..not responding...
[180465.588148] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[180645.590667] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[180825.598223] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[180825.598320] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[180825.598333] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[180825.598345] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[180825.598354] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[180825.598360] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[181005.606753] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[181005.606847] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[181185.619985] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[181185.620008] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[181185.620013] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[181185.620314] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[181215.636217] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 timing out command, waited 30s
```

I have tried a different USB cable with identical results. I have not opened the device, as, according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9FcCDcXJcY) it seems to not have a standard SATA connector I could fit into another enclosure.

What are further steps I can take to fix the drive and hopefully preserve the data contained?

Comment: I'm not a Linux guy, but it sounds as if you're "talking" to the USB (SCSI) portion, not the drive. So either fault with the drive itself or in electronics on the PCB. Does the drive spin up even, can you hear/feel it buzz if you power it on?

Comment: Yes, the drive spins up normally, as far as I can tell (no abrupt stops or strange noises).

Comment: Addendum: It does spin down (gently) after a second or two.

Comment: Then it's the drive itself. So drive spins up (it boots basically), tries to access SA (service area, it's own OS), fail and spins down. Most likely causes for that are surface damage and/or weak/failing heads. Best option would be sending to data recovery specialist.

Comment: That's a bummer, but thanks for your assessment of the situation. I'll have to find out if the data is worth the price of a specialist.

Comment: Price for that often depends on: is is large 'chain' or franchise -> then you often pay more. In lower wage counties you often pas less (so ship abroad). Low price does not mean bad, for example $300 data recovery (company) is relatively cheap but that does not mean they deliver sloppy work. This all being said, in $500 price range is where you'd be in general (western countries).